# How can I raise the fee of a transaction in Bitcoin Wallet App?

Tags: transaction-fees, unconfirmed-transactions, bitcoin-wallet-app, replace-by-fee

I am using the Bitcoin wallet app from bitcoinj.org. I sent a payment with a low fee so it's been pending for 8 days. I wrote the developers and they only replied with auto. Beneath is what I got:

> Q: An outgoing payment doesn't get confirmed for a longer time.
> A:
> The reason is the same as for the previous question: The Bitcoin
> network is running at its capacity limit. As a sender, if you have
> time critical payments you should use Send coins > Options > Fee >
> Priority to pay a higher fee. The fee can also be increased after
> sending (Transaction > Options > Raise fee). Just be aware about how
> much you spend on fee; it's sometimes more than expected.

Now I can't find a place to do that. When I click on any sent transaction nothing happens.